# Error: /etc/network/interfaces/ is a directory!

Tags: debian, networking

Trying to edit the prior using `nano /etc/network/interfaces/` in Debian and get the following error:

```
Error: /etc/network/interfaces/ is a directory!
```

I need to fix this?

Comment: Can you show what you get if you do `ls -l /etc/network/interfaces` ?

Comment: have you try to edit the file without the temrinating `/`

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify a file name for `nano`. That what you specified is a directory (ending in a slash `/`, gives that a away apart from the error message).

On my Ubuntu system that is actually a file (and nano gives no error if it is and you have the trailing `/`)

Answer (score -2):

I know what you are up to, you can edit a directory using `vi` editor. But when you use `nano` you will get a error. So edit the directory using `vi` editor.

```
vi /etc/network/interfaces/
```

Comment: The notion that someone should use `vi` over `nano` to make the task easier to comprehend is certainly a novel approach...

Comment: Hey you can move mountains using vi also it helps when working with visudo and cron-jobs. Thats why I prefer vi to nano..